# How to automatically execute command in iTerm2

Tags: iterm2

I want to source ~/.zshrc when I open iTerm2 automatically
How any settings I can set in iTerm2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your setting page and change the **Sent text at Start**

[image]